# Spring Boot Pagination JPA how to convert findById into a Page Object having all the objects with different Id

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tables table A,Table B and table A_B. Table A_B has columns
|A_id | B_id | Updated_date|
|     |      |             |

I have to fetch all the A_ids based on given single B_id which will eventually be a
List<A_B objects> based on given input of b_id.

Now using each element of this List<A_B objects> i have to query table_A and get individual records,  add all those record and return a Page with given PageRequest.

Generally , using repo.findAll(SpecificationBuilder,PageRequest) is used for a single table and it returns a complete list. In my case it will be a single record and i have to hit repo again and again to get a List. How can i solve this issue where i can add each record to my Page model and return it.

I tried creating a Page from the  List<A_object> but the whole purpose of Page is sending the PageRequest directly to JPA and not make Page in Java or have a sublist. In my case i will get individual records and i need to add all those and sent back as Page.